# Desktop Application

Tags: windows, desktop-application

I want to develop a desktop application for Windows!

I want it to be visually appealing. Which software should I use?

Comment: Visually appealing will have little to do with the language/software you are using. You need a good graphic designer for that.

Comment: i mean i tried in visual studio but coudnt think of a way of giving it a great look!!!

Comment: If you are to have any hope of getting an answer you are going to need to be able to explain what you mean by "visually appealing".

Comment: @david- just like a twitter desktop app... its luks beautiful...

Comment: http://www.digimantra.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2009/07/destroy-twitter.gif

Answer (score 2):

Use [Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Presentation_Foundation).

It is the standard and preferred technology for this as provided by Microsoft.

Comment: Yeah, and nice components from a vendor, as already suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Use Microsoft Visual Studio Express http://www.microsoft.com/express/Windows/
or Adobe Flash Professional (and export it as AIR app)

Comment: hey thanks for a fast reply..

Comment: i cheack visual studio for windows app but couldnt find a  way to make it visually appealing... i want the app to look beautiful\

Comment: you're welcome :)
Then Flash will definitely help unleash your creativity.

Answer (score 0):

Use components from a component vendor. I find [DevExpress](http://www.devexpress.com/) very nice, but there are also others.